# construct hyperlink in wpf C#

Tags: c#, wpf

how can i insert a TextBlock control in a Hyperlink in c# coding. similar to 
`<TextBlock> <Hyperlink>a</Hyperlink></textblock` in C#. i'm unable to find content property in Hyperlink. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to use [Inlines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.span.inlines.aspx) to add Hyperlink to TextBlock and to add text to HyperLink

```
TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
Hyperlink link = new Hyperlink();
link.Inlines.Add("Click me");
textBlock.Inlines.Add(link);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a TextBlock. I use something I ran across and works great for me.

XAML:

```
< TextBlock >
    < Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://yoursite.com" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate" >
        Click Me
    < /Hyperlink >
< /TextBlock >
```

Code Behind:

```
private void Hyperlink_RequestNavigate(object sender, 
    System.Windows.Navigation.RequestNavigateEventArgs e) {
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(
        new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri)
     );
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

===============================

I have seen this alot as the solution but was getting an error at Process.Start. Did some more reading and found out this is best for Web Apps. Whether it is or is not the solution posted above solved my hyperlink issue.

```
protected void Hyperlink_RequestNavigate(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e)  { 
    Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri)); 
    e.Handled = true; 
}
```

===============================

Comment: How to replace "Click Me" with binding?